# Check for whole number in AS 3

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I check for a whole number in AS 3?

Example:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < thumbs.length(); i++) 
{
      if((i / this.thumbsRow) === wholeNumber)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(int(k) === k)
  trace("whole number");
else
  trace("float");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the modulo operator:

```
var isWhole:Boolean = foo % 1 == 0;
trace("Is whole number: " + isWhole);
```

Where 'foo' is the number you're checking. Modulo gives you the remainder of dividing the first number by the second number. For any whole number, there would be no remainder.